# Undefined References eclipse using libav

Tags: compiling, eclipse, c++

I am trying to install the newest version of libav from the [libav website](https://libav.org/). Currently being version 11.7. I have unziped, configured, make, and make install.

For ./configure I had tried using various options. As a precaution if i add/removed an option with ./configure, I would do it with a fresh copy of the source code and also cleared the libs and headers.

The additional options were:

```
./configure --enable-libx264 --enable-librtmp --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree --enable-muxer=mp4 --enable-muxer=h264 --enable-demuxer=aac --enable-demuxer=h264 --enable-encoder=libx264 --enable-encoder=libfdk_aac --enable-decoder=libfdk_aac --enable-version3
```

I also tired it without any additional options.

In the eclipse IDE, I have configured the compiler to include the /usr/local/libs in its search path, and also included the libs themselves. 
[image: Eclipse c++ libs/search path]

I don't know what else to do. I keep getting undefined references.

Edit (Additional information):
I have simplified the code to were it is only the function av_register_all();. I still get errors. Here are a few:

```
/usr/local/lib/libavcodec.a(libx264.o): In function `X264_frame':
/usr/local/src/libav/libavcodec/libx264.c:140: undefined reference to `x264_picture_init'
/usr/local/src/libav/libavcodec/libx264.c:142: undefined reference to `x264_bit_depth'
/usr/local/src/libav/libavcodec/libx264.c:160: undefined reference to `x264_encoder_reconfig'
/usr/local/src/libav/libavcodec/libx264.c:166: undefined reference to `x264_encoder_reconfig'
/usr/local/src/libav/libavcodec/libx264.c:173: undefined reference to `x264_encoder_reconfig'
/usr/local/src/libav/libavcodec/libx264.c:192: undefined reference to `x264_encoder_reconfig'
/usr/local/src/libav/libavcodec/libx264.c:232: undefined reference to `x264_encoder_reconfig'
/usr/local/src/libav/libavcodec/libx264.c:237: undefined reference to `x264_encoder_encode'
/usr/local/src/libav/libavcodec/libx264.c:243: undefined reference to `x264_encoder_delayed_frames'
/usr/local/src/libav/libavcodec/libx264.c:237: undefined reference to `x264_encoder_encode'
/usr/local/src/libav/libavcodec/libx264.c:179: undefined reference to `x264_encoder_reconfig'
/usr/local/src/libav/libavcodec/libx264.c:198: undefined reference to `x264_encoder_reconfig'
/usr/local/src/libav/libavcodec/libx264.c:186: undefined reference to `x264_encoder_reconfig'
/usr/local/lib/libavcodec.a(libx264.o): In function `X264_init_static':
/usr/local/src/libav/libavcodec/libx264.c:577: undefined reference to `x264_bit_depth'
/usr/local/lib/libavcodec.a(libx264.o): In function `X264_close':
/usr/local/src/libav/libavcodec/libx264.c:278: undefined reference to `x264_encoder_close'
/usr/local/lib/libavcodec.a(libx264.o): In function `X264_init':
/usr/local/src/libav/libavcodec/libx264.c:314: undefined reference to `x264_param_default'
/usr/local/src/libav/libavcodec/libx264.c:319: undefined reference to `x264_param_default_preset'
/usr/local/src/libav/libavcodec/libx264.c:415: undefined reference to `x264_param_parse'
/usr/local/src/libav/libavcodec/libx264.c:416: undefined reference to `x264_param_parse'
/usr/local/src/libav/libavcodec/libx264.c:417: undefined reference to `x264_param_parse'
/usr/local/src/libav/libavcodec/libx264.c:418: undefined reference to `x264_param_parse'
/usr/local/src/libav/libavcodec/libx264.c:459: undefined reference to `x264_param_apply_fastfirstpass'
/usr/local/src/libav/libavcodec/libx264.c:465: undefined reference to `x264_param_apply_profile'
/usr/local/src/libav/libavcodec/libx264.c:501: undefined reference to `x264_param_parse'
/usr/local/src/libav/libavcodec/libx264.c:519: undefined reference to `x264_encoder_open_148'
/usr/local/src/libav/libavcodec/libx264.c:532: undefined reference to `x264_encoder_headers'
/usr/local/lib/libavcodec.a(opusdec.o): In function `opus_decode_subpacket':
/usr/local/src/libav/libavcodec/opusdec.c:382: undefined reference to `avresample_is_open'
/usr/local/lib/libavcodec.a(opusdec.o): In function `opus_decode_frame':
/usr/local/src/libav/libavcodec/opusdec.c:221: undefined reference to `avresample_is_open'
/usr/local/lib/libavcodec.a(opusdec.o): In function `opus_init_resample':
/usr/local/src/libav/libavcodec/opusdec.c:163: undefined reference to `avresample_open'
/usr/local/src/libav/libavcodec/opusdec.c:169: undefined reference to `avresample_convert'
/usr/local/lib/libavcodec.a(opusdec.o): In function `opus_decode_frame':
/usr/local/src/libav/libavcodec/opusdec.c:236: undefined reference to `avresample_convert'
/usr/local/lib/libavcodec.a(opusdec.o): In function `opus_flush_resample':
/usr/local/src/libav/libavcodec/opusdec.c:118: undefined reference to `avresample_convert'
/usr/local/lib/libavcodec.a(opusdec.o): In function `opus_decode_subpacket':
/usr/local/src/libav/libavcodec/opusdec.c:414: undefined reference to `avresample_close'
/usr/local/lib/libavcodec.a(opusdec.o): In function `opus_decode_flush':
/usr/local/src/libav/libavcodec/opusdec.c:616: undefined reference to `avresample_close'
/usr/local/lib/libavcodec.a(opusdec.o): In function `opus_decode_close':
/usr/local/src/libav/libavcodec/opusdec.c:640: undefined reference to `avresample_free'
/usr/local/lib/libavcodec.a(opusdec.o): In function `opus_decode_init':
/usr/local/src/libav/libavcodec/opusdec.c:704: undefined reference to `avresample_alloc_context'
/usr/local/lib/libavcodec.a(pthread_frame.o): In function `ff_frame_thread_free':
/usr/local/src/libav/libavcodec/pthread_frame.c:522: undefined reference to `pthread_join'
/usr/local/lib/libavcodec.a(pthread_frame.o): In function `ff_frame_thread_init':
/usr/local/src/libav/libavcodec/pthread_frame.c:648: undefined reference to `pthread_create'
/usr/local/lib/libavcodec.a(pthread_slice.o): In function `ff_slice_thread_free':
/usr/local/src/libav/libavcodec/pthread_slice.c:110: undefined reference to `pthread_join'
/usr/local/lib/libavcodec.a(pthread_slice.o): In function `ff_slice_thread_init':
/usr/local/src/libav/libavcodec/pthread_slice.c:211: undefined reference to `pthread_create'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

To be more specific the libs are installed in the /usr/local/lib directory, the headers are installed /usr/local/include/libav* .
I have also tried compiling my source code by command line rather than the IDE giving the same result.

command line argument:

```
c++ -L/usr/local/lib test.cpp -lx264 -lavresample -lavformat -lavutil -lavcodec -lavutil -lz -lavutil -o out
```

Comment: If you're trying to build an old codebase against the latest version of libav, then perhaps the issue is that `av_free` is apparently deprecated - see this related [so] thread [ffmpeg/libavcodec memory management](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18047320/4440445)

Comment: I just tried to simplify the code. I have made simple c++ program with the library headers for avcodec and avformat and just added the function av_register_all(); Still receiving many errors.

Comment: Have you tried building from the command line? One thing I just noticed is you appear to have `libavutil` above all the other av libraries: assuming eclipse follows a top-to-bottom link ordering, you may need to play with the list order - link order is important in symbol resolution

Comment: @steeldriver Okay, so this seems to have been the best response. I have changed the order of the librarys to -lavformat -lavutil -lavcodec. It reduced to a smaller amount of unresolved dependencies. I had added them to the original question.

Comment: If there are *recursive* dependencies then you may need to take extra steps to resolve them - see for example this [so] question [Why does the order in which libraries are linked sometimes cause errors in GCC?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45135/why-does-the-order-in-which-libraries-are-linked-sometimes-cause-errors-in-gcc). Unfortunately I'm not familiar enough with libav to suggest a specific solution.

Comment: @steeldriver The problem was the order and also including some additional libraries. You were correct. I started by not including any libraries to see the first thing it complained about. Then I added and googled the libraries each function appreared in until eventually I included all the libraries that it was asking for and in the order.  Thank you!

Comment: as you managed to solve it, perhaps you could take a few minutes to write up an answer - it may help others who have the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that the libav libraries must be specified in a specific order to resolve all dependencies. I was able to find the correct order by compiling with no additional libraries first. Then when the compiler complained about a unresolved reference, I located the library by googling what library the function belonged to. I did this until all dependencies were resolved. The resulting order was

1. avformat
2. avcodec
3. avutil
4. z
5. x264
6. pthread
7. avresample

Using g++ to compile the code, I used this command:

```
c++ ./main.cpp -L/usr/local/lib -lavformat -lavcodec -lavutil -lz -lx264 -lpthread -lavresample -o output
```

And this is what it should look like in eclipse:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have this block:

```
extern "C" {
#include<avformat/avformat.h>
#include<avformat/...whatever....h>
}
```

In files demux.cpp and codec.cpp as well.

**EDIT**

Tried to do what you did and worked fine. Here is what I did:

```
$ cat av.cpp 
extern "C" {
#include <libavformat/avformat.h>
}
int main(void)
{
  av_register_all();
  return 0;
}
$ g++ av.cpp -lavformat
$ ./a.out
```

HTH

Comment: I have done this but in the .hpp not the cpp. That shouldn't make a difference right?

Comment: Added it to the .cpp files, also did not work.

Comment: Do you have any other .cpp files in your project? If you do then add the same block in all of them.

Comment: I have check that also and it also has not worked . I added some error to the question and i sort of think that it has something to do with the linking.

Comment: Just saw your edit. Did you do it with the latest version of libav 11.7? If I use the one in the Ubuntu repository it works but it doesn't have all the functions I need because it's an older version

Comment: I installed deb packages from the ubuntu repositories. If you have both libav from repositories and your own compiled from source you may be better off uninstalling the packaged one. When you have both the compiler might be picking headers from 1 version and the linker - libraries from the other, leading to your linkage problem.